# read.table function and stdin

Tags: r, stdin

I have a tab-delimited text file that I am trying to load into R with the `read.table` function. The first few lines of the script look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
data <- read.table(args[1], header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote="")
# process the data
```

This works. I had originally tried to get R to read the data from standard input, but was unsuccessful. My first approach...

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
data <- read.table(stdin(), header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote="")
# process the data
```

...didn't seem to work at all. My second approach...

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
data <- read.table("/dev/stdin", header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote="")
# process the data
```

...read the data file but (for some reason I don't understand) the first 20 or so lines get mangled, which is a big problem (especially since those lines contain the header information). Is there any way to get `read.table` to read from standard input? Am I missing something completely obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`?stdin` says:

> `stdin()` refers to the ‘console’ and not to the C-level ‘stdin’
>   of the process.  The distinction matters in GUI consoles (which
>   may not have an active ‘stdin’, and if they do it may not be
>   connected to console input), and also in embedded applications.
>   If you want access to the C-level file stream ‘stdin’, use
>   `file("stdin")`.

And:

> When R is reading a script from a file, the *file* is the
>   ‘console’: this is traditional usage to allow in-line data …

That’s the probable reason for the observed behaviour. *In principle* you *can* `read.table` from standard input – but in most (almost all?) cases you’ll want to do this via `file('stdin')`.

Comment: Brilliant. file("stdin") instead of stdin() or "/dev/stdin" did the trick.

Comment: Nine years later, `read.table(file("stdin"))` still does the trick.